# BroadCastReceiver and Eventhandler

Tags: android

Does onClickListener and anything in event handler consider broadcastreceiver ???

```
OnClickListener processOnClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
                  // my Code is here 
    }
};
```

Comment: Please read the docs again. What is the context of comparing Broadcast receivers and `OnClickListener` interface ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NO**

Broadcast receivers receive intents and have nothing in common with [`OnClickListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) interface

`OnClickListener` is a callback interface whose `onClick` method is called when a view is clicked

Answer (score 1):

No. Broadcast receivers are used to communications between activities, not for actions in the activity components